# Read a keypress in Expect script

Tags: tcl, expect

I'm newbie with Expect and need a simple functionality: wait for a user to press ANY key and then continue the flow. What command in the script should I use for this purpose ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

[This entry](http://wiki.tcl.tk/14693) on the tcl wiki should answer your question, but it does not use expect.

Comment: +1 for referring to something I wrote long ago! Note that it still requires that the key produce a character. I note this because I remember seeing a user who used the shift key as the “any key”, and then wondered why nothing was happening. After that, I rewrote my code to ask for the space bar to be pressed. :-)

Comment: @donal I'm just getting into Tcl for an application scripting language for a project at work, and I've been seeing your name around a lot. Thanks for all your contributions. :)

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try this out:

```
expect "*\r"
expect_continue
```